# How to get all videos of Channel from Youtube API with statistics

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

With the below URL I am able to get the channel videos but how to get video statistics (viewCount, likeCount etc) along with it?

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={MY_API_KEY}&channelId=UCz22l7kbce-uFJAoaZqxD1A&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20`

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#usage,

The statistics response will contains the things you want.

Comment: Ya, I know that......... but I want statistics is the same (Single) json.
In other words, I should get all the videos along with statistics of each video

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still useful to you since it's been so long, but it may help someone else. Just add statistics to the part. See below:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={MY_API_KEY}&channelId=UCz22l7kbce-uFJAoaZqxD1A&part=snippet,id,statistics&order=date&maxResults=20
```

Comment: This will not be valid unless you specify a bearer token. API Key will only support `snippet` and `id` parts